# How can I aggregate by similar row results and then group by a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

| type | name |
| --- | --- |
| api1 | joe |
| api0 | jim |
| notapi | joe |
| api3 | jim |
| notapi3 | jim |
| other | mary |
| misc | joe |
| notapi0 | mary |

I want the result to have the count of the similar types (`[api0, api1, api0], [other], [misc], [notapi, notapi0, notapi3]`):

| name | api | notapi | misc | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| jim | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| mary | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I've tried using a case statement but it just counts everything under a single column. The types will have lots of varying names but they'll all start similarly. For example, all api ones will look like "api-43149g", "api-gk3jf", non-apis will look like "notapi-3123", "notapi-gjsn4". So I know I'll need to use "like 'api%'" and "like 'notapi%'". Looking to do this in PostgreSQL

Thank you

Comment: Here, does "similar" mean they have the same letters once digits are removed?

Comment: Just updated to be more clear. The types will all start similarly. So the APIs will start with 'api', then non-apis will start with 'notapi', and so on. So I can use the LIKE statement to determine which is which. For example: api-34914, notapi-34812, api-23194, notapi-fj284j

Comment: `select name, count(*) filter (where type like 'api%') as api, . . . from yourtable group by name;`

Comment: You've changed your question. I could provide a simple solution for the initial version of your question that would work with any type in case you add more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve different columns if you use a new **case expression** for each column you want in the result. Also note that `COUNT()` ignore NULL so the **case expression** does not need to return anything when the condition is not met. (Altenatively use `else NULL` in the **case expressions**.)

```
select
      name
    , count(case when type like 'api%' then 1 end) as api
    , count(case when type like 'notapi%' then 1 end) as notapi
    , count(case when type in ('misc')  then 1 end) as misc
    , count(case when type in ('other')  then 1 end) as other
from your_table
group by
      name
```

**btw** placing a **case expression** inside the aggregation function is known as "conditional aggregation".

**nb** a "case statement" exists in very few products and is different to a **case expression**

**alternate syntax**

Postgres allows for use of "filter" with [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html), using that syntax:

```
select
      name
    , count(*) filter where type like 'api%' as api
    , count(*) filter where type like 'notapi%'as notapi
    , count(*) filter where type in ('misc') as misc
    , count(*) filter where type in ('other') as other
from your_table
group by
      name
```

also note I have for example, used `in ('misc')` but when there is only one value to check, use `= 'misc'`